# NiFi: Joining the two csv files for lookup and then selecting columns from flowfile (csv fle) based on look up file

Tags: csv, join, merge, apache-nifi

This is what I am trying to achieve. all of them are csv files

Flowfile (csv) -

```
col1_raw, col2_raw, col3_raw, col4_raw
1   ,        2     ,     3     ,    4
1   ,        2     ,     3     ,    4
```

Look up file1 (csv)

```
col_name_raw , col_name_business, class
col1_raw     ,   col1_business  ,  Secret
col2_raw     ,   col2_business  ,  Public
col3_raw     ,   col3_business  ,  Secret
col4_raw     ,   col4_business  ,  Public
```

Look up file2 (csv)

```
class,  action
public,  copy
secret,  nocopy
```

output (csv) of flowfile should be

col2_business, col4_business

2          ,         4

2          ,         4

So basically I am filtering the columns of flowfile based on the action listed lookup file2. Also changing the raw column name to business column name as per lookup file1. In SQL it is very easy but in Nifi how can I achieve this using existing processors. Please help.

Comment: your look up file 1 and 2 are static or you receive all file in zip or someting like this ?

Comment: lookup file1 and 2 are static and each one is csv file. They do not need to come from flowfile. They can be referenced from some folder or location from the processor.